# When should i use /*+ APPEND */ during INSERT

Tags: java, sql, oracle, performance, insert

As a part of daily importing a job i am `TRUNCATING` the data for tables and inserting data from raw file.

Some tables import usually large data like in the range `200,000` rows but some tables import less data in the range `5,000` to `30,000` rows.

For large table import it will take lot of time during insertion and at the end sometimes it will end with performance issue.

I am using Java for processing this imports into Oracle table. So this table is not hardcoded and import according to their job.

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE " + tableName);    --for truncating table

return "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" +
                columnData.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).map(ColumnData::getName).collect(joining(", ")) +
                ", SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT) VALUES (" +
                values.stream().collect(joining(", ")) +
                ", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";  --for insertion into table
```

I would like to know is it good idea to use `/*+ APPEND */` hint during insertion and does it improve performance during insertion ? As read in the oracle article for less insertion its not good idea to use `/*+ APPEND */` as it will end up affecting the performance issue.

Comment: [This website](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/append-hint) hints, that `/*+ APPEND */` only works with `INSERT .. SELECT` statements. This would then not work for you

Comment: I would highly recommend using `PreparedStatement`s instead of this

Comment: I think it would be better to use a bulk insert in a PL/SQL procedure to import 200.000 rows.

Comment: and use "reuse storage" in your truncate command if your just gonna insert similar amount again

Comment: @f1sh does it has something to do with performance ?

Comment: @olafur yes its going to insert near by same amount again so how can i use "reuse storage" with truncate and whats the advantage of that ?

Comment: I think unless you have `insert into ... select ...` you should use the `APPEND_VALUES` hint to get the same effect.

Comment: yes i think i tried to execute plan for with insert and using /*+ APPEND */ insert and both took almost same time..so i guess /*+ APPEND */ will not work here

Comment: Define [extarnal table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-external-tables-concepts.html#GUID-44323E01-7D72-45EC-915A-99E596769D9E) on your file and perform `INSERT INTO ...  SELECT ... FROM external table` - here you may use the `APPEND` hint (e.g to compress the data) and the performance will be comparable with the *SQLLoader*.

Comment: `APPEND` only works with `INSERT SELECT`. `APPEND_VALUES` only works with `INSERT VALUES`. But you need to understand what they do rather than just including hints because they might be faster. Direct path insert locks the entire table, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program almost certainly will not benefit from the `APPEND` hint.  Batching commands is more likely to improve performance.

The `APPEND` hint is helpful when inserting a *huge* amount of data.  It improves performance by writing data directly to data files, and bypassing updating memory structures, REDO, and UNDO.  But we must be willing to accept the consequences of those shortcuts - the operation locks the entire table, and the data will not be recoverable.

200,000 rows is *not* a huge amount of data.  (Unless each row contains large files stored in LOB columns.  For performance questions, it's often more useful to speak about bytes instead of rows.)  If we make a wild assumption that each row has 1,000 bytes, that's still only 200 megabytes of data.  Writing 200 megabytes to memory, UNDO, and REDO, shouldn't add more than a few seconds to the run time.  Eliminating those seconds won't help much.

Batching is the best way to improve the performance of your program.  Every database command has a significant amount of overhead, mostly for network lag and parsing.  Combining multiple commands can significantly reduce that overhead and boost performance.

Check if your database API or framework has a batching option.  Enabling it might be as simple as a configuration change.  You don't need to batch everything, just combining one hundred rows at a time will eliminate 99% of the overhead

If you don't have a batching option, can build your own solution by concatenating strings.  The below code demonstrates two different ways to insert multiple rows in a single command.

```
create table table1(a number, b number);

insert into table1
select 1, 1 from dual union all
select 2, 2 from dual;

insert all
    into table1 values(3, 3)
    into table1 values(4, 4)
select * from dual;
```

Comment: Can you please give an example about batching commands so that i can try to check the performance ?

Comment: @Andrew I added two examples to my answer.  If you're looking for a JDBC batching example, I'm not an expert in that, but there are plenty of examples online.